# JavaScript how to replace dots with a break line in a string

Tags: javascript

In my project I have a form for messages the user can send to me, when the validation fail I need to display the errors for him, but the errors the I get from the backend is an object of arrays and I extracted the values and concatenated it in one string by this

```
    let errors = Object.values(data);
    let errorsMarkup = ""

    for (let i = 0; i < errors.length; i++) {
      errorsMarkup += `${errors[i]}`;
    }
```

now the string will be sentences that shows the errors separated by dots, I need it to be separated by break lines to show the user the errors one by line so I made this

```
    errorsMarkup = errorsMarkup.replace(/\./g,'<br>');
```

and I call the sweet alert to show the errorsMarkup

```
    Swal.fire({
      icon: 'error',
      title: 'Oops...',
      text: errorsMarkup
    });
```

but this is what I get

[image: The Output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use html  property to pass HTML

```
Swal.fire({
  icon: 'error',
  title: 'Oops...',
  text: '',
  html: errorsMarkup
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `text` with `html`:

```js
Swal.fire({
  icon: 'error',
  title: 'Oops...',
  html: errorsMarkup
});
```

You can refer to the official docs for help: https://sweetalert2.github.io/#usage